# Need help outtping json with python

Tags: php, python, json

Im in need of help outputting the json key with python. I tried to output the name "carl".

Python code :

```
 from json import loads
 import json,urllib2

class yomamma:
  def __init__(self):
      url = urlopen('http://localhost/name.php').read()
      name = loads(url)
      print "Hello" (name)
```

Php code (for the json which i made):

```
<?php
$arr = array('person_one'=>"Carl", 'person_two'=>"jack");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

the output of the php is :
{"person_one":"Carl","person_two":"jack"}

Answer (score 1):

I'll just assume the PHP code works correctly, I don't know PHP very well.

On the client, I recommend using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) (installable through `pip install requests`):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://localhost/name.php')
data = r.json()
print data['person_one']
```

The `.json` method returns a Python dictionary.

Taking a closer look at your code, it seems you're trying to concatenate two strings by just writing them next to eachother. Instead, use either the concatenation operator (`+`):

```
print "Hello" + data['person_one']
```

Alternatively, you can use the string formatting functionality:

```
print "Hello {}".format(data['person_one'])
```

Or even fancier (but maybe a bit complex to understand for the start):

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost/name.php')
print "Hello {person_one}".format(**r.json())
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try that now :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import json
person_data = json.loads(url)
print "Hello {}".format(person_data["person_one"])
```